# Parsing JSON Data in Windows Phone 8

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I would like to know , how we can parse a JSON data which is received from a rest web service. The sample JSON data is given here `{"success":true, userName:true}`

I am seeing numerous articles about this, as I am new to this, don't know the best method.

Thanks in advance
Sebastian

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you to build classes of your json or else you could go to [this](http://json2csharp.com/) site and generate the classes.

a sample snippet would be like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
public Response response { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
public int errorFlag { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("Score Detail")]
public JObject ScoreDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Have a look at this article fore more:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/africaapps/archive/2013/02/25/parsing-json-in-windows-phone-apps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Json.NET makes this sort of thing super easy - https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Lots of easy to follow examples here - http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio 2013, you can directly generate the de-serialized class using the "paste as json" feature. 
You can then parse the json using this code

```
        public T GetObject(string json)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer jsonParser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            var obj = jsonParser.ReadObject(stream);
            return (T)obj;
        }
```